# Getting DLL load failed error when trying to import filters from skimage

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, scikit-image

I am using Anaconda 4.8.0 with a Python 3.6.9 environment. Using Numpy 1.18.1, SciPy 1.4.1 scikit-image 0.16.2. Six 1.13 is also installed although I am not sure how critical that is. I want to do some simple edge detection on an image but I am having some trouble importing the packages required. I read an image, convert it to gray scale and want to apply edge filters. 
My code looks like this

```
from PIL import Image 
from pathlib import Path
from skimage.filters.edges import sobel_h, sobel_v
pass_folder = Path('D:/Pycharm files/neuralnetwork/results/pass')
im = Image.open(pass_folder/'test.PNG').convert('L')
edges_h = sobel_h(im)
edges_v = sobel_v(im)
im.show(edges_h)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arne.biermans/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_8.py", line 5, in <module>
    from skimage.filters.edges import sobel_h, sobel_v
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .edges import (sobel, sobel_h, sobel_v,
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\edges.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..restoration.uft import laplacian
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .deconvolution import wiener, unsupervised_wiener, richardson_lucy
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\deconvolution.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import fftconvolve, convolve
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 289, in <module>
    from . import sigtools, windows
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .windows import *
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows\windows.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import fftpack, linalg, special
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "C:\Users\arne.biermans\Conda envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import _fftpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

If I just import skimage and use `print(skimage.__version__)` I get `0.16.2` so skimage seems to be installed correctly. I need to use Python 3.6 because I also need to use Tensorflow.
I also tried to install Numpy-MKL but that results in an error. I also tried `from skimage.filters import sobel_h, sobel_v` but that doesnt work either. Maybe this is trivial but I am unable to find what is wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Lately I have spent more time trying to various packages to work than actual coding.

Edit: I completely removed Anaconda and reinstalled from scratch. When running a Jupyter notebook I can import modules just fine and print their versions to see if they installed correctly. In Pycharm, now nothing loads, every module results in the error 'The module could not be found'. Pycharm is pointing to the right interpreter. I'll be giving up on Pycharm and just use Jupyter notebooks. I do not have the time to try and fix this mess.

Comment: it shows problem with importing `fftpack` so you may need to install Fortran package [fftpack](http://www.netlib.org/fftpack/)

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by re-installing Pycharm.